# Debug Breakpoints - Display variable values in Log Message

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, nslog

When I use the *Log Message* as *Action* in a Breakpoint is it still possible to print current variable values to the log output ?

When using a NSLog inline something like this is possible ...

```
NSlog(@"<DeleteArea> <State> CallToggle %i",[[deleteCardState userInfo] intValue]);
```

however in a breakpoint as *Log Message* using e.g. ...

```
@"<DeleteArea> <State> CallToggle %i",[[deleteCardState userInfo] intValue]
```

does not work.

How do you output formatted variables in breakpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as a Debugger Command as follows:

```
expression (void) NSLog(@"<DeleteArea> <State> CallToggle %i",[[deleteCardState userInfo] intValue]);
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. However I noted that this will add an additional log line to the output, like "(char *) $70 = 0xd8f71437". Can this be *turned off*?

Comment: Yeah, the result should be typecast to (void).