# How to evaluate a statement in XCode debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode4.6

So every other IDE I have ever used, if there is some statement in the code with a break point set, there is a way to evaluate that statement to see what it is returning, ie immediate windows in visual studio, or using watch menu.  Is there anything somewhat equivalent in XCode, or some way to evaluate a statement within a section of code?

ex:

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint([FGO BoundingBox], touchLocation))
```

Is returning false, so I'd like to see what `[FGO BoundingBox]` is evaluating to, but I can't seem to figure anything out short of changing the code to store it in an intermediate variable.  Assuming I have a break point on this line in XCode what is the easiest way to see what this statement will return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
po [FGO BoundingBox]
```

or

```
po NSStringFromCGRect([FGO BoundingBox])
```

also check out

```
help expression
```

in the debugger.

Comment: This is returning `[no Objective-C description available]` on statements that would return something if I placed them into the code, seems a bit weird.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia - The variable has to be "in scope" before you can use "po" on it.  Eg, you must have stepped through the code past the point where FGO is set before doing `po [FGO BoundingBox]`.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia (And understand that you key these commands into the console window.)

Comment: @HotLicks it is in scope, and typing `expression [FGO boundingBox]` works perfect, so I guess I just have to prefix with expression.  Thanks for the answer (while typing `po [FGO boundingBox]` returned the error stated above).

Comment: check out this SO question, it might help: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667479/debug-breakpoints-display-variable-values-in-log-message/18667621#18667621)

Comment: Ah, yes!!  If the expression you want to print is not an Objective-C object, just use "p" instead of "po".  A CGRect isn't an object, but a C struct.

Comment: (This is one of those things that you trip over occasionally, slap your head, and move on, without even thinking about it.)

Answer (score 0):

Break on that line, then ***step in*** to the "`BoundingBox`" function and step to the end of it (or where it returns something) and you should see what it's returning.

Comment: I tried this, but it returns another call that isn't evaluated by the IDE, seems there should be an easy way to just see what something is going to return without stepping into all the details of the method call.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia - You are learning why it's not always wise to combine statements vs use a few temps here and there.

Comment: @HotLicks While I agree to some point, this still seems like a real weakness in the IDE.